# Can you draw automata graphs directly into a post in StackExchange:CS?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Can you draw automata graphs directly into a post in StackExchange:CS using MathJax?

Answer (score 11):

No, you can not.

You can use any free-hand drawing app and upload the resulting PNGs.

If you want to use TikZ, I have built [scripts that can help you](http://akerbos.github.io/sesketches/).

Comment: Nice job! Thanks for all the work that went into it.