# Is there a way to draw derivation trees with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

Is there a known way to draw derivation trees (proof trees, typing derivation trees, ...) with MathJax?

Currently, I embed trees by the following ways as workarounds:

- Draw a tree using my PC with LaTeX, convert it to an image, and upload it, or

  [image: a proof tree of modus ponens; (A \to B) and A are written above a horizontal line, and B is written below the line]
- Use `\cfrac` for a simple tree, or

  \[
    \cfrac{A \to B \qquad A}{B}
  \]

  ```
  \\[
    \cfrac{A \to B \qquad A}{B}
  \\]
  ```
- Write an ascii art in a code block

  ```
  A → B    A
  -----------
       B
  ```

I want to use [bussproofs.sty or something](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468/114888) to draw trees with LaTeX/MathJax, especially for complex trees. (But bussproofs.sty is not supported by MathJax.) Writing trees as text is useful for future edits. Is there a way to draw them?

Comment: Bussproofs will be in MathJax v3.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the info! I confirmed that there is a merged pull request for that: https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3/pull/331

Comment: [Related](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1145/98).

Answer (score 3):

I use `\dfrac` (or `\cfrac`). ([Example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92874/in-hindley-milner-system-how-can-i-prove-that-let-id-x-x-in-id-id-is-well-type/92913#92913).) And yes, it's painful.

Please don't post images of math. They're completly inaccessible to blind people, they can't be searched (not that math search works well on the web today, but it's more likely to improve than image content search), they can't be edited.

Comment: We can write [alt-text](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/embedded-content-0.html#alt) of images for accessibility issues. Even so, yes, images can't be edited both by blind people and by non-blind people.